# Rotating image using RotateTransform issue with offsets

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Here is my XAML:

```
<Image 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Source="{Binding Input, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapConverter}}">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" CenterX="100" CenterY="100"></RotateTransform>
                </Image.RenderTransform>

            </Image>
```

I'm binding image to data source and use converter to get Bitmap. That part works. However, I want to make it rotate and I set RotateAngle in my VM. Problem is - all images have different dimensions, I don't know how to set CenterX and CenterY. Is there any other way to just change orientation without calculating additional X and Y?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have time to test this myself but I think RenderTransformOrigin might work for you.

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"

 Source="{Binding Input, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapConverter}}" 
 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" >
        </RotateTransform>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

</code></pre>